# std::make_from_tuple doesn't compile without constructor

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, default-constructor

I have a simple struct:

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    
    // A(int a, int b, int c) : a{a}, b{b}, c{c} { }
};
```

The constructor is commented for now. I am trying to create object of type `A` in a such way:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
A a = std::make_from_tuple<A>(std::move(t));
```

but it doesn't compile. MSVC gives a message:
`<function-style-cast>: cannot convert from initializer_list to _Ty`.
After I uncomment the constructor of struct `A`, it starts working.

The question is: why `std::make_from_tuple()` requires a user-defined constructor instead of default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the implementation of `make_from_tuple` in the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple#apply-2):

```
namespace std {
  template<class T, class Tuple, size_t... I>
    requires is_constructible_v<T, decltype(get<I>(declval<Tuple>()))...>
  constexpr T make-from-tuple-impl(Tuple&& t, index_sequence<I...>) {   
    return T(get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
  }
}
```

It uses parentheses (`()`) to initialize `T` with direct initialization. Since `A` is an aggregate, it cannot use parentheses for initialization in C++17, and can only use curly braces (`{}`) for list initialization.

It is worth noting that [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) makes it possible to use parentheses to initialize aggregates in C++20, so your code is [well-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/E8c3hnvPd) in C++20.